# Can someone please explain this recursive JS code to calculate exponents?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I can't understand this recursion even though it's a really simple example. When it goes to `power(base, exponent - 1);` what is that supposed to do? How are things being multiplied when power keeps getting invoked until `exponent` equals 0?

```
function power(base, exponent) {
    if (exponent === 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript. Removed java tag.

Comment: Alter the problem to get a smaller instance `power(base, exponent - 1)` and *use* it with the "solved" part `base` - the "*use*" in this example would be just multiplication.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker But it is sort of the same syntax so I thought people from there would know too.

Comment: For future reference, if this is not purely academic, one should use `Math.pow` which is probably much faster because it can be natively optimized. This snippet will run in `O(exponent)` time (fairly bad, though not bad if all you're doing is taking the 2nd and 3rd power, etc.). If one was implementing this from scratch and performance was an issue, one would use algorithms such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start from the beginning.

Let's say you call `power(base, 0)`.  Since `exponent` is 0, the function returns 1.

Now, let's say you call `power(base, 1)`.  Since `exponent` isn't 0 this time, the function calls `power(base, exponent - 1)` *and multiplies it by* `base`.  (That's the key here...it takes the result from the recursive call, and adds its own twist.)  Since `exponent - 1` = 0, and `power(base, 0)` is 1, the result is effectively `base * 1`.  Read: `base`.

Now on to `power(base, 2)`.  That ends up being `base * power(base, 1)`.  And `power(base, 1)` is `base * power(base, 0)`.  End result:  `base * (base * 1)`.  Read:  `base` squared.

And so on.

In case it wasn't obvious, by the way, this function will only work with non-negative integer exponents.  If `exponent` is negative, or is even the tiniest bit more or less than a whole number, the function will run "forever".  (In reality, you'll more than likely cause a stack overflow, once recursion eats up all of your stack.)

You could fix the function for negative powers with some code like

```
if (exponent < 0) return 1 / power(base, -exponent);
```

As for non-integers...there's no good way to solve that other than throwing an exception.  Raising a number to a non-integer power makes sense, so you don't want to just truncate the exponent or otherwise pretend they didn't try to do it -- you'd end up returning the wrong answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is similar to `Math.pow()`; it raises the `base` argument to the `exponent` argument.

For example, `2 ^ 4` is `16`, so `power(2, 4)` would return `16`. The `if()` statement checks to see whether the exponent (power) is zero and returns `1` if it is - any number raised to the power 0 equals 1.

The last line

```
return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
```

Is a recursive function that calls `power()` from within itself however many times specified by the value in `exponent`.

---

I'll try to explain recursion from the bottom up, or "from the middle" shall we say; it's probably easier to understand.

The bottom most call of `power()` takes `2` and `1` as it's arguments, and will return `1`. This return value is then used in the second up call of `power()`, so this time the arguments passed are `2` and `2`, which outputs `4`, and so on until the top-most call to `power()` is passed `2` and `4` which returns `16`.

Comment: Yeah but where does the end result come from. In my mind, the function will keep getting invoked and exponent keeps going down to zero, so the function should return 1. But I just don't get where 32 comes from in `power(2, 5);`

Answer (score 3):

Using a 2^3 example:

```
power(2, 3);
```

calls:

```
function power(2, 3) {
    if (3 === 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2 * power(2, 2); //called
    }
}
```

which leads to:

```
function power(2, 2) {
    if (2 === 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2 * power(2, 1); //called
    }
}
```

which leads to:

```
function power(2, 1) {
    if (1 === 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2 * power(2, 0); //called
    }
}
```

which leads to:

```
function power(2, 0) {
    if (1 === 0) {
        return 1; //returned
    } else {
        return 2 * power(2, -1);
    }
}
```

which leads to:

```
function power(2, 1) {
    if (1 === 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2 * 1; //returned
    }
}
```

which leads to:

```
function power(2, 2) {
    if (2 === 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2 * 2; //returned
    }
}
```

which leads to:

```
function power(2, 3) {
    if (3 === 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2 * 4; //returned
    }
}
```

which ultimately returns 8, which is 2^3.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the initial call is `power(10, 3)`...

```
  v-----first power() call returns base * (result of next power() call)
        v-----second power() call returns base * (result of next power() call)
              v-----third power() call returns base * (result of last power() call)
                   v------result of last power() call returns 1
(10 * (10 * (10 * (1))))
                   ^-----return 1
              ^-----return base * 1 (10)
        ^-----return base * 10 (100)
  ^-----return base * 100 (1000)
```

---

Or go down the left, and up the right. Each line is a subsequent call to `power()` starting with `power(10, 3)`...

```
return base * power(base, 2);  // return base * 100 (1000)
return base * power(base, 1);  // return base * 10   (100)
return base * power(base, 0);  // return base * 1     (10)
return 1;                      // return 1             (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

base = 10
power = 3

10 * power(10,2)

10 * 10 * power(10,1)

10 * 10 * 10

maybe ok for positive integers...

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to explain this with some maths.

```
f(x,y) = x^y                     # (1) function definition
       = x * x * x * ... * x     # (2) multiply x with itself y times
       = x * (x * x * ... * x)   # (3) rewrite using parentheses for clarity
       = x * (x^(y-1))           # (4) replace the second part by (1) notation
       = x * f(x, y-1)           # (5) replace again by using f(x,y) notation according to (1)

f(x,0) = 1                       # base case: x^0 = 1
```

Following this you can see that `f(x,y) = x * f(x, y-1)`.

You can also see where

```
if (exponent === 0) {
    return 1;
}
```

comes from, namely the base case that something to the 0th power always equals 1: `f(x,0) = 1`.

That's how this recursion was derived.