# What is the logic from the else block on this code?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time understanding the else block. I know it's supposed to raise the base parameter to the exponent parameter. But how does it work?

```
var power = function(base, exponent){

    if (exponent === 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
    }

};

power(2, 2);
```

Comment: It's a recursive function, calling itself with different arguments.

Comment: It's a recursive means of exponentiation. *a^b = a * a^(b-1) = a * a * a^(b-2) = ...* and we know *a^0 = 1*.

Comment: The `else` is actually not needed so you can get rid of it and just put the return statement after the if or better yet, do this: `return !!exponent || base * power(base, exponent-1)`

Comment: Ok I understand that it's calling the function power within the fuction. But why exponent-1 ? I know that if I take out the -1 it gives back and error. What does it exactly doing there?

@webarto I'm trying to understand the code behind.

Comment: @RufioLJ If you don't decrease the exponent, how are you ever going to reach the base case?

Comment: With each time, you call the same function, you decrease the value of the exponent in order to reach the bottom of the recursion (which is, every number raised to the power of 0 is equal to 1).
If you don't substract, the recursion won't have bottom to reach and you will have stackoverflow (oh the irony)

Comment: @RufioLJ We need something that will allow us to loop. The `exponent` variable is to let us know how many times we have to loop. We do `exponent - 1` so we not only have some means of breaking out of the loop (when `exponent === 0`) but also to loop `exponent` times. We could've used a for loop instead if we wanted to. Don't worry, I was confused about this too -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610545/can-someone-please-explain-this-recursive-js-code-to-calculate-exponents

Comment: @David wow thanks. I kinda understand after you say it's needed to loop. I imaged it being a for loop, but it's looping because the function is called within the function. I'm going to keep reading until I understand it well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
power(base, exponent - 1)
```

is really just `base * power(base, exponent - 1)`. But if we keep thinking about what is happening in those function calls, we see this:

```
base * ... pow(base, exponent - n)
```

Let's try `power(2, 4)`:

```
2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * (1))))

2 * power(2, 4 - 1);
```

`power(2, 4 - 1)` simplifies to

```
2 * power(2, 3 - 1)
```

which simplifies to

```
2 * power(2, 2 - 1)
```

which simplifies to

```
2 * power(2, 1 - 1)
```

and that simplifies to `1` since `exponent` will be `0`. When we put it all together this is what we get:

```
2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 1
```

Comment: I don't understand how power(2, 4 - 1) gets to be 2 each time it loops :/ Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RufioLJ Because `pow(...)` means `2 * pow(...)` which means `2 * pow(...)` which means `1`. So each 2 before the call is mutliplied by the return value of the inner call. The return value will either be 2 or 1 (1 in the end when `exp === 01.

Comment: @RufioLJ I know it's confusing. But what exactly don't you get?

Comment: I think I got it, but I'm not sure. Because the else returns base each time it loops it's base * base * ... * base...  right? I was confused on where the 2's keep coming from. I think I've got it, It's the power function looping inside giving base * base * base * .... * base ... depending on the exponent number until it gets to 0.

Comment: lol thanks a lot it was kinda hard to make sense, but thinking about it for some time really clears it up.

Answer (score 1):

for an input `power(2/*base*/,2/*exponent*/)`

**ITERATION** 1: Since `2/*exponent*/` is not equal to `0`: on the entry, it executes the `else` part.

hence it should return `2 * power(2,(2-1)/*which is 1*/)`

**ITERATION 2**: again, there is a call to `power()` function with arguments `2/*base*/ and 1/*exponent*/`
`power(2,1)` is executed in `else` part : `returns 2 * power(2,0)`

**ITERATION 3**: again there is a call to `power()` function with arguments `2/*base*/ and 0/*exponent*/`

> Since exponent is 0, it executes the if part and returns 1, which
>   completes the second iteration returning 2 to it. that completes the
>   first iteration returning 4 from it.